# How to copy the link href itself to the clipboard when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a link that users can click on it, and then the `href` itself will be copied to the clipboard. Since I'm new to JS, I couldn't do it with the information I found, because I saw examples where people would click on a button to copy the url, or it would copy the URL of the address bar.

Here is my code, and  `+ artworkUrl +` is dynamically filled.

```
<a id="get-app-artwork" href="' + artworkUrl + '" target="_blank">Copy the cover URL</a>
```

How can I make this url be copied to the clipboard on click? Every option I found uses different approaches. As I'm new to this, I don't know how to apply to this situation, where I have a link and want to copy the URL of it when clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to copy the href value. That's not what the mentioned link is about. This is not an input, it is a link.

Comment: if you want a link to copy something on click instead of navigating somewhere on click, you probably shouldn't be using an `a` tag. Maybe use a button, or style some text to look like a link, and attach a `(click)` even handler to that element and copy the needed text to the clipboard there.

Comment: So you get the link and than you set the input value and than you copy it

Answer (score 25):

Use the Clipboard API, specifically the [`writeText` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText).

```html
<a href="' + artworkUrl + '" onclick="copyURI(event)">Copy cover URL</a>
```

```js
function copyURI(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(evt.target.getAttribute('href')).then(() => {
      /* clipboard successfully set */
    }, () => {
      /* clipboard write failed */
    });
}
```

EDIT 18/07/2020 : There is a missing `)`  to properly close the `writeText(` function.

Comment: It seems you may also need `onclick="copyURI(event)"` in the anchor tag in order for the function to be called appropriately.

Comment: Requires a secure origin / localhost otherwise it raises "Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard is undefined".

Comment: For me it did not work with <a> tag and href, I got null in return. I only used <img> and attribute 'src' and it is working great.

Answer (score 1):

#### With ***jquery***

```
$("a #get-app-artwork").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText($(this).attr("href"));
 });
```

Comment: This works with a little change since navigator.clipboard.writeText returns a promise and you should wait for its result. Hence, the third line should be changed to: `navigator.clipboard.writeText($(this).attr("href")).then(() => {});`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<div class="text-center">
<button class="margin-top-10 btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="copytext('#text1')">Скопировать ссылку текущей страницы</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copytext(el) {
    var $tmp = $("<textarea>");
    $("body").append($tmp);
    $tmp.val($(el).text() + window.location.href).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $tmp.remove();
}   
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div class="blog">
<div id="primary">
<div class="padding-box">
<div class="container">
<div class="row header" id="main_content">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">   
<main id="main">    
        <article id="post-2651" class="post-2651 post type-post status-publish format-aside has-post-thumbnail hentry category-teksty-i-ssylki-prostye-resheniya tag-jquery post_format-post-format-aside">

 

    


<div id="text1" class="padding-10"><p><b></b></p>
<p></p></div>

<div class="text-center">
<button class="margin-top-10 btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="copytext('#text1')">Скопировать ссылку текущей страницы</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function copytext(el) {
    var $tmp = $("<textarea>");
    $("body").append($tmp);
    $tmp.val($(el).text() + window.location.href).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $tmp.remove();
}   
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).